# Blazor Show Error Msg when run the app in VS2019 Preview 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I followed instruction in this page:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/

My PC system : Windows 10 Pro/ Version 1803/ OS build: 17134.950

1) Have updated VS2019 Preview to version 16.3.0 Preview 2.0

2) Install the SDK and Runtime from this link:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0#runtime-3.0.0-preview8

2a) SDK 3.0.100-preview8-013656

```
 selected and installed: x64 and x86  

 Net Core Installer :x64 | x86
```

2b) Runtime 3.0.0-preview8-28405-07

```
  instruction not clear so :

 Selected and installed : 1) and 2) x64 and x86

 1) ASP.NET Core/.NET CORE: Runtime & Hosting Bundle

 2) ASP.NET Core Installer: x64| x86
```

3) run this command in:  COMMAND Promt , Power Shell as well as use package manager console in VS2019

dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview8.19405.7

Launch VS2019 Preview and create a Blazor WebAssembly App

click the rebuild to build and it shows below Error Messages:

**Problem:**

CS0234  The type or namespace name 'LayoutAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components' (are you missing an assembly reference?) for these pages:

Counter.razor.g.cs 
FetchData.razor.g.cs
Index.razor.g.cs
_imports.razor.g.cs

Please help how to resolve this problem.

**Update:**

1) With just x64 Net core SDK, After creating the Blazor project, it will contain empty projects for client/share/server.

2) So, I installed another x86 net core Sdk. With both X64 & X86, this will show the Msg at the step of selecting Template: The .NET Core SDK is installed in multiple locations. Only templates from the SDKs installed at 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\' are displayed.But Blazor project will not be empty but have the same problem as above after you did a rebuild solution.

3) uninstall x64. With x86 only, it will still show the msg:
The .NET Core SDK is installed in multiple locations. Only templates from the SDKs installed at 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\' are displayed.But Blazor project will not be empty but have the same problem as above after you did a rebuild solution.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can be helped by following this github issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12712

Comment: That issue predates preview8 by 2 weeks.

Comment: So ??? This is from the same issue, dated Aug 13, 2019: I am getting the same error using the latest Visual Studio Enterprise Preview with the latest templates preview 8 and latest .Net Core 3.0 preview 8.

Comment: no repro: I just upgrade to 16.3.0 Preview 2.0, created a new app and it just worked 'out of the box'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why would you use preview 2.0? We're on preview 8.

Comment: That is the framework, Core 3.0/preview8 . I was talking about VS, 16.3/preview2